# Three Way Interaction in mgcv

Tags: interaction, gam, mgcv

I am interested in implementing a three-way interaction in mgcv but while there has been some discussion both here and on Cross Validated, I have had trouble finding an answer to how exactly one should code a three-way interaction between two continuous variables and one categorical variable. In my study, I have only four variables (socioeconomic class (Socio), sex, year of death (YOD), and age) for each individual and I am curious how these variables explain the likelihood of someone being buried with burial goods (N=c.12,000).

I have read Pedersen et al. 2019 and have elected to not include global smooths in my model. However, I am not certain if this means I should also not include the lower order interaction terms in my three-way interaction model. For example, should my code be:

```
mgcv::gam(Goods ~ Socio + te(Age,YOD,by=Socio,k=5), family=binomial(link='logit'), 
        mydata, method='ML')
```

should I still include the lower order terms within the three-way interaction:

```
mgcv::gam(Goods ~ Socio + s(Age,by=Socio,k=5) + s(YOD,by=Socio,k=5) + te(Age,YOD,k=5) + 
        ti(Age,YOD,by=Socio, k=5), family=binomial(link='logit'),mydata,method='ML')
```

or is there a different means of coding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to perform a test on the interaction, then you are better off not decomposing the `te()` into main and interaction effects. This is because the models

```r
y ~ te(x1, x2) # main + interaction in one smooth model

y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + ti(x1, x2) # decomposed model
```

aren't *exactly* equivalent:

- you have to be very picky about setting `k` on all the terms such that these models are using the same number of basis functions, and
- the decomposed model uses more smoothness parameters than the `te()` version, so is slightly more complex a model *even if you get all the bases are roughly of comparable size*

Note you *are* including a global smooth in the second model: this term `te(Age,YOD,k=5)` will be an global smooth of `Age` and `YOD` over the whole data set.

The decomposed version of your first model would be:

```r
Goods ~ Socio +
  s(Age, by = Socio) +
  s(YOD, by = Socio) +
  ti(Age, YOD, by = Socio)
```

Setting things up to test if you need the factor by terms or not would require more work but I think you'd be better off do that post-hoc on the `te()` model, where you can compare the fitted surfaces by differencing them.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for clearing that up, particularly regarding the global smooth in the second model. My overall goal is to test whether the three-way interaction is a better fit (using AIC) than the model which only includes the pairwise interactions so judging from what you have said here, it seems like a better idea to go with the decomposed version. However, I am not certain I understand what you mean by your final paragraph so please correct me if I misunderstand.

Comment: By three-way do you mean you want to test if you need `f + te(x,z, by=f)` over `f + te(x,z)`? AIC doesn't test fit, it is an approximation of LOO prediction error, and would amount to choosing using a much lower p value threshold than 0.05 (i.e. 0.1 or higher - I forget the actual number now)

Comment: Apologies, my wording was confusing. Yes, that is exactly what I am testing and my plan was to compare AIC values and weights

Comment: Gavin is correct about the p value using AIC. See here at the bottom of the page. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118445/what-is-the-basis-of-setting-critical-p-value-value-in-stepwise-regression

Comment: Perhaps I am not following. My plan was to compare the two models using ```AIC()``` which is relatively common from what I have seen?